# Use $lookup on a double nested array

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use an _id saved in a double nested array to find and attach data from a different document. It essentially looks like this:

```
doc1 = {
    _id: ObjectId,
    ...other stuff...,
    firstArray: [
        ...other stuff...,
        secondArray: [
            other_id: ObjectId
        ]
    ]
}
```

```
doc2 = {
    _id: ObjectId,
    ...the stuff I want...
}
```

Not every entry in secondArray is going to contain an other_id field, only some. This has gotten me close to the result I want except that the firstArray field contains an entry for the total number of entries in the secondArray field. I think I'm just missing one step to essentially undo the one of the two $unwinds.

```
doc1.aggregate([
            { $match: { _id: req.params._id }},
            { $unwind: "$firstArray" },
            { $unwind: "$firstArray.secondArray" },
            { $lookup: { 
                from: "doc2", 
                localField: "firstArray.secondArray.other_id", 
                foreignField: "_id", 
                as: "firstArray.secondArray.other",
            }},
            { $addFields: {
                "firstArray.secondArray.other": {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$firstArray.secondArray.other", 0]
                }
            }},
            { $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                ...other stuff...,
                firstArray: { $push: "$firstArray" },
            }},
        ]);
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Please add sample data and your query here https://mongoplayground.net/ and update the story with the link

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another `$group` stage to reconstruct the `"secondArray"` structure, in general it's easy to remember that for each `$unwind` action you do, you'll need to counter that with  another `$group` in order to restore the initial structure.

In order to do that you'll need some kind of a unique identifier for `firstArray` so you can group by it, if it doesn't exist you can add an `_id` that is the index of the element in the array like so:

```
{
    "$addFields": {
      "firstArray": {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $zip: {
              inputs: [
                "$firstArray",
                {
                  $range: [
                    0,
                    {
                      $size: "$firstArray"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          as: "item",
          in: {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$$item",
                  0
                ]
              },
              {
                _id: {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$$item",
                    1
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now `firstArray` has a unique field `_id` that we can later use to group on like so:

```
... the pipeline ...

{
    $group: {
      _id: {
        id: "$_id",
        first: "$firstArray._id"
      },
      secondArray: {
        $push: "$firstArray.secondArray"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id._id",
      firstArray: {
        $push: {
          secondArray: "$secondArray"
        }
      },
    }
  }
```

You will need to add support for all the "other stuff" you defined in your own pipeline, but this pipeline flow is the way to go.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CW80nk2rF-k)